# GANs on color images

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

Most (PyTorch) [open source GANs work on  MNIST dataset](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/PyTorch-GAN), i.e. gray level image.

Can I use a GAN on each channel of a color image, then combine the result?

Answer (score 2):

You can just have your generator and discriminator generate and classify 3-channel images - speaking in terms of implementation, make them work on `B x 3 x H x W` tensors instead of `B x 1 x H x W`, as they do for MNIST.

You can't just use your GAN on each channel separately and concatenate at the end, because you would have no way to ensure that each channel corresponds to the same image. Say you're generating celebrity faces by first generating red channel, then green and finally blue. How would you make sure that you don't get a female sample for the red channel and a male for the green?

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to do it. In fact, some GANs have 'the number of channels' as input, and I did not need to tweak the tensor size. 
As I am new to GANs, donno if I can ask you another question, do they overfit if I increase the number of epochs? How to know I have got the best generator?

Comment: On StackOverflow the convention is to ask separate questions for separate concerns - this helps other users discover your questions and their answers in the future. I am no GAN expert, but the optimization problem with GANs is difficult in itself, because every generator can be tricked by some discriminator and vice versa. You'd have to ask another question or check out the literature, but don't expect straightforward answers.